# Порядок работы деструктора, совместно с try catch

Tags: php

Почему, в этом коде

```
 <?php
class Orator {
    private $name;
    function __construct($name){
        $this->name = $name;
        echo 'Создан объект ' . $this->name . '<br>';
    }

    function __destruct() {
        echo 'Уничтожен объект ' . $this->name . '<br>';
    }
}
function outer(){
    $obj = new Orator(__METHOD__);
    inner();
}
function inner(){
    $obj = new Orator(__METHOD__);
    echo 'Внимание, вбрасывание!<br>';
    throw new Exception('Hello');
}

echo 'Начало программы<br>';

try {
    echo 'Начало try-блока<br>';
    outer();
    echo 'Конец try-блока<br>';
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Исключение: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br>';
}
echo 'Конец программы<br>';
```

объект не сразу уничтожается? 
Ведь после конструктора, сразу указан деструктор.

Сейчас это работает вот так:

```
Начало программы
Начало try-блока
Создан объект outer
Создан объект inner
Внимание, вбрасывание!
Уничтожен объект inner
Уничтожен объект outer
Исключение: Hello
Конец программы
```

А мне интересно, почему работает не так?

```
Начало программы
Начало try-блока
Создан объект outer
Уничтожен объект outer
Создан объект inner
Уничтожен объект inner
Внимание, вбрасывание!
Исключение: Hello
Конец программы
```

Comment: Потому что объект живет внутри области. пока область действует - живет и объект... когда внутри `outer` происходит вызов `inner`, то, по сути, `outer` еще не отработал. Т.к. идет последовательная обработка инструкций.... И outer ждет отработки в inner. Как только в inner прошли инструкции, контекст возвращается в outer и только после этого объект уничтожается.... если ты `inner()` поместишь после `outer()` ты увидишь как раз, что outer помрет раньше, чем придет очередь выполнять метод `inner()`

Comment: `Ведь после конструктора, сразу указан деструктор.` - И было бы странным, если бы выполнение методов в классе зависело от их последовательного расположения внутри класса. Просто представить сложно класс с 20-тью методами, в которых чем выше метод, тем первее срабатывает :)) Расположил деструктор вторым по порядку и ржёшь над коллегами :))

Answer (score 1):

У вас метод __destruct() объявлен после метода __construct(), но это не значит, что они будут срабатывать по очереди.

Обычные методы срабатывают тогда, когда их вызывают, а вызывать их можно в любом порядке и сколько угодно раз. В вашем случае __destruct() и __construct() вызываются не явно __construct() - при создании объекта, __destruct() вызывается при уничтожении объекта.